# Removing parts of a string in SSIS derived column Expression

Tags: ssis

I am not sure if this is possbile but I am trying to remove a character from a string.

The string is LBÂ EMMELOORDÂ but I do not want the 'Â' to be inserted into the table destination. My knowledge is a bit lacking here but I can find answers to this question if the character was not part of the string. i.e; there was a space in between . 
But that is not the case. What I have at the moment is the following expression:

```
(DT_STR,30,1252)REPLACE(Relation,SUBSTRING(Relation,FINDSTRING(Relation,"Â",1),
LEN(Relation)),"")
```

This however does not work. The error message I receive is that the type cast is not possible.

Comment: Would it work without the `SUBSTRING?` i.e. `Replace(Relation,"A","")`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your column source is DT_WSTR and you are trying to convert to DT_STR. how about:

```
(DT_STR,30,1252)replace(Relation,"Â","A")
```

That would allow you to convert and not lose meaning.

This is likely not the only character causing issues though.